# Finding monochromatic subset of triangular lattice

Tags: graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let
$$ \Lambda = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2:y\geq x\} $$
the upper triangular lattice and $d:\Lambda\to\{1,\dots,c\}$ a coloring (i.e. an arbitrary function) on $c$ colors. Let $k\geq2$. I am looking for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $m_1<m_2<\dots m_k$ and $n_j \in [n,m_j]\cap\mathbb{N}$, $j=2,\dots,k$, such that the set
$$ B = \{(n,m_1),(n,m_2),\dots,(n,m_k), (n_2,m_2),(n_3,m_3),\dots,(n_k,m_k)\}$$
is monochromatic (i.e. all its points have the same color). See the picture below for an example.

[image]

From the ergodic proof of multidimensional Van der Waerden theorem it is easy to show that such set $B$ always exists; moreover, one also has
$$ s(B) := \max_{1\leq j\leq k}m_j-n_j \leq m_1$$
My question is: can I take $B$ such that $s(B)$ is bounded by something depending only on the number of colors $c$?

Comment: It looks so. You may simply find this pattern in $N$ lower rows where $N$ depends only on $c$. Also usual  
2-dimensional van der Waerden is pretty enough: your set contains large grid of size about $N/2$ where you may find anything you need.